# Angular RxJS - How to monitor progress of HTTP Get Request (not file)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

How to utilize Angular HTTPClient's `progress` event to show progress in percentage of Get request which does not necessarily a file request?

Currently HTTPClient's `progress` event fires after request completion. I am hoping to work with `Content-Length` at back end and determine percentage of content loaded at front end.

I am loading a large amount of rows for a grid and need to show incremental progress on UI. Is it possible?

Answer (score 15):

I know this question is older but, i stumbled upon this while searching for an answer to a similar problem and since there is no accepted answer i post my solution.

I recently implemented a generic way to display a progress bar for every request no matter the type in angular 8.

First i created a `HttpInterceptor` which would automatically intercept every http call where the `reportProgress` option is set to `true`.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpProgressInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService // my personal service for the progress bar - replace with your own
  ) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.reportProgress) {
      // only intercept when the request is configured to report its progress
      return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
            // here we get the updated progress values, call your service or what ever here
            this.spinnerService.updateGlobalProgress(Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100)); // display & update progress bar
          } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            this.spinnerService.updateGlobalProgress(null); // hide progress bar
          }
        }, error => {
          this.spinnerService.updateGlobalProgress(null); // hide progress bar
        })
      );
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

You need to register this interceptor in your `module` of course:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpProgressInterceptor, multi: true },
    ...}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Basically we're done here, only thing left is that we need to change the way we call our apis. If you want a specific request to be monitored using this interceptor you need to tell angular to report the progress on the HttpRequest:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  myGetMethod() {
    const url = "api/data/load/big/data";
    const req = new HttpRequest("GET", url, {
      reportProgress: true  // this is important!
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
}
```

This way of calling the `httpClient` api deliveres a different object when calling `.subscribe` so we need to take care of that when calling the `myGetMethod()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.myGetMethod().subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
      const responseData = event.body;
      console.dir(responseData); // do something with the response
    }
  });
}
```

We could also listen here for the `HttpEventType.DownloadProgress` event and update the progress values inside this component - but that was not the point of my example.

**Hint**: if you encounter the problem that `event.total` is undefined - you must check whether your REST backend REALLY is providing the `Content-Length` header - if this header is missing, you will not be able to calculate the progress!

anyway, i hope this will help somebody someday

Comment: I also add  near `reportProgress: true`  following option: `observe: "events"` - this makes that progress bar refresh more often

Comment: Can you add this to stackblitz and share the link?

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
import { HttpEventType, HttpClient, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
```

...

```
const request = new HttpRequest('GET', url,  {
  reportProgress: true
});

http.request(request).subscribe(event => {

  // progress
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
    console.log(event.loaded, event.total); 
    // event.loaded = bytes transfered 
    // event.total = "Content-Length", set by the server

    const percentage = 100 / event.total * event.loaded;
    console.log(percentage);
  }

  // finished
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
    console.log(event.body);
  }

})
```

Comment: The three `console.log` prints just once, after the request has completed.
`loaded, total: 4 undefined`
`progress: NaN`
`response: null`

Comment: What angular version are you using?

Comment: I am using `4.4.3`.

Comment: I don't understand your printed values? Is total empty?

Comment: Yes, total is always `undefined`. Don't you think total shows `Content-Length`?

Comment: Yes, the total value depends on the `Content-Length`-Header. Are you sure it is set in the response? And how large is your response? Only 4 bytes?

Comment: I am setting it with `response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(serializedDataTable).ToString());`. It's a Nancy endpoint. Response is around 10KB. But this header doesn't show in *Network*. I am using webpack proxy for API requests. Any ideas?

Comment: If the header isn't visible in network in your browser, your server isn't sending it. Different problem, different question ;-)

Comment: Yeah, problem is, any header except `Content-Length` is sent. For some reason, content-length isn't getting through.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```js
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload/file', file, {
    reportProgress: true
    });
```

Next, pass this request object to the **HttpClient.request()** method, which returns an Observable of **HttpEvents**, the same events processed by interceptors:

```js
    // The `HttpClient.request` API produces a raw event stream
    // which includes start (sent), progress, and response events.
    return this.http.request(req).pipe(
    map(event => this.getEventMessage(event, file)),
    tap(message => this.showProgress(message)),
    last(), // return last (completed) message to caller
    catchError(this.handleError(file))
    );
```

Finally you can use that to help

```js
    /** Return distinct message for sent, upload progress, & response events */
    private getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>, file: File) {
    switch (event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      return `Uploading file "${file.name}" of size ${file.size}.`;

    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      // Compute and show the % done:
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      return `File "${file.name}" is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`;

    case HttpEventType.Response:
      return `File "${file.name}" was completely uploaded!`;

    default:
      return `File "${file.name}" surprising upload event: ${event.type}.`;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's written "not file"