# How to capture API call's progress and show it in MAT-Progress bar with custom text message?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

**Apologize**, If someone asked the same question already.

Thanks.

**chat.service.ts**

```
initiateDemoRequest(clientReqId): Observable < any > {
    return this.httpClient.post('https://my-endpoint-goes-here',
        clientReqId,
        {
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events'
        }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));

}
```

**createRequest.component.ts**

```
indicator = 0;
progress = 0;

this.myservice.initiateDemoRequest(clientReqId).subscribe( data => {
    if (data.type === HttpEventType.Sent) { // am assuming SENT is used to when api call started requesting to server
        this.progress += Math.round(100 * data.loaded / data.total);
        console.log('what is progerss', this.progress);
      } else  if (data.type === HttpEventType.Response) { // am assuming rESPONSE is used to when getting reponse from server        
        this.progress += Math.round(100 * data.loaded / data.total);
        console.log('this.progress', this.progress);
      }

      // window.open('https://trying-to-open-url-in-another-page.com', '_blank')
});


<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" *ngIf="indicator"  value="indicator"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Another attempt of using interceptor after watching **YouTube** video

Created loader service and interceptor like below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {
  public isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false) ;
  constructor() { }
}
```

interceptor.ts

```
constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('event ?', event.type);
        }
        return event;
      }),
    );
  }

<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loaderService.isLoading | async" mode="determinate" value="connectionProgress"></mat-progress-bar>
```

**Note: I dont see any error in above implementation. but i've not clue on how to capture http's event and log it.**

**What i want to acheive?**

I want to show progress bar with custom message like below

- if request progress is completed 50% - show 'Your connection is
  progress'.
- if request progress is completed 100% -  show 'Now your connected
  with Secure customer service. start chatting'. Then redirect to new
  window for chatting

**How its happening?**

I've a table, each rows has option to trigger popup `connectWithRepresentative()`
**(no issues here am able to trigger the popup)**.

Showing `connect` button to initiate my request. it will take some time. **during this am try to show above message to customer** to make sure they are all set ready to chat
else will error message.

Sorry for not sharing minimal reproducible **stackblitz** code. currently am not able to access plunker. stackblitz for some reason. don't know why.

Need your guys help.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48461386/angular-rxjs-how-to-monitor-progress-of-http-get-request-not-file

Comment: @Edison . yes I've seen this and other similar implementation already in SO and tried the same. but anyhow i couldn't achieve it. Do you have any examples similar to my requirement. ?